# Why are difference bt. even and odd displays?

Tags: java, random, println

I've got something strange here with display.

The code
`System.out.println("");`

works perfectly with odd numbers only, but not with even numbers. Why?

Thanks!

Check the below code:

```java
import java.util.*;
public class oddeven{
    public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Odd or Even? Please insert:");
    int number = in.nextInt();
    if(number > 0 && number % 2 == 1){
        System.out.println(""); // does not work with even, WHYWHYWHY
        System.out.println("Number " + number + " is odd.");
        } else {
        System.out.println("Number " + number + " is even.");
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: define "does not work" ? What do you expect it to do?

Comment: Because you only print that when `number` is odd?

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`System.out.println("");` is present inside `if` statement, so it will only print, when `if` condition is true.
One way will be to put it outside `if` statement.

```java
...
System.out.println("");
if(number > 0 && number % 2 == 1) {
    System.out.println("Number " + number + " is odd.");
}
...
```

Comment: Sure, Please upvote and mark this as an answer if it has helped. Thanks